# Can you pass more then 1 Argument in a discord.py command?

Tags: python, list, discord.py

What I want is to pass a list into a function, but for some reason I always get an error.

Example:

```
L=["Hello"]
@client.command()
async def enroll(ctx, L: list):
    #processing
    await ctx.channel.send(L)
```

Comment: It looks to me like you set your variable `L` and then you defined a function which can take a list as a parameter. But you aren't showing how you're calling the function and passing the list in. You need to call it somewhere in your code like `enroll(L)`

Comment: Please specify the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Make it accept a string, then parse it into a list using `str.split`.

```
@client.command()
async def enroll(ctx, things: str = "Hello"):
    parsed_things = things.split(',')
```

Then pass it a string separated by commas:

```
[p]enroll thing1,thing2
```